# How to add elements at the beginning of an Arduino String. Similar to JS unshift();

Tags: c++

I have an unknown size `String`, but with a maximum size of 8 and I want to make sure its size will always be 8 by adding 0(zeroes) at the beginning of the String.
For example the inputted `String` is "5687" and I have to add 0 until it's size is 8: "00005687".

```
String str = "5687";
while(str.length() < 8) {
  // add 0 at the beginning of str
}
```

Unlike JavaScript, Arduino C++ doesn't have anything like unshift() or does it ?

How can I achieve my goal ? Thank you.

P.S: I am using an ESP32 and only a couple of Strings, because the handler of ESPAsyncWebServer usually return String parameters.

Comment: Instead of thinking about it like "insert '0' into the string", think about it as "appending the string `str` to the end of the string `"0"`".

Comment: Basically `str = String("0") + str;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    String str = "5687";
while(str.length() < 8) {
  str = String("0") + str;
}
```

Comment: I think the loop condition should be `str.length() < 8`, else the loop will run for a string with length 8 and result in length 9.